Where to Find Implementations of Modelica Stream Connector
Are there any examples of how to implement a Stream Connector?
The Modelica Specification seems to support the idea that Stream Connectors, compared to Through and Across variables, are better suited for modelling convective transport phenomena. This sounds good, but I don't see any helpful examples of how they are implemented in real life e.g. none of the Modelica Standard Libraries use this connector. Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

The Modelica Standard Library Fluid use Stream connectors.
A basic example is Fluid/Examples/Tanks/EmptyTanks for a start.
If you look up for instance Fluid/Pipes you can see in the code that functions inStream() etc are used.
A very basic example on usage of inStream() and actualStream() you have here on Stackoverflow How to construct a balanced connector for liquids in Modelica?

If you think the linked answers solves the issue, then why not close-vote as a dupe?

The post author asks for some guiding examples to get started. I think it is important to show that Modelica Standard Library do use it. However the code is complicated and the post on Stackoverflow I wrote myself long time ago got some very good answers around a basic example, from key people in the Modelica community.

Asking for offsite resources is off-topic anyway

All Modelica users has access to the Modelica Standard Library and thus common to refer to in the way I do. Not that much "offsite" in practice IMHO.
